# What are the 4 components of chiral bispinors and the 4 components of the Dirac spinors?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation

I'm looking for a straightforward answer as to what do the 4 components of the chiral bispinors represent, compared to what do the 4 components of the dirac spinors represent. (Of course, the chiral bispinors rely on the chiral basis of the $\gamma$ matrices, and the dirac spinors on the dirac basis).

Which components are differentiated by **charge**? Which by **spin**? Which by **chirality**?

Can we have a simple, straightforward table about the meaning of the 4 components for both types of bases? I am asking this because it is an absolutely fundamental and important information to have clear in mind, and at the same time it should be extremely quick to formulate (!), however finding this information in a concise way has proven difficult. Can any of you do this simple table (comparing the 2 bases), and possibly link a source?

Comment: This might help a bit: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345660/spin-part-of-the-dirac-spinors?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

These are the conventions I found.

In the [Dirac basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Dirac_basis) the bispinor components are defined by
fermion/antifermion (here labeled as $+,-$) and spin component $S_z$ ($\uparrow,\downarrow$):
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_{+\uparrow}\\ \psi_{+\downarrow} \\
\psi_{-\uparrow}\\ \psi_{-\downarrow}
\end{pmatrix}$$

In the [chiral basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Weyl_(chiral)_basis) the components are defined by
chirality ($L,R$) and spin components $S_z$ ($\uparrow,\downarrow$):
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_{L\uparrow}\\ \psi_{L\downarrow} \\
\psi_{R\uparrow}\\ \psi_{R\downarrow}
\end{pmatrix}$$

There is also the [chiral basis (alternate form)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Weyl_(chiral)_basis_(alternate_form)),
which swaps $L$ and $R$ chirality:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_{R\uparrow}\\ \psi_{R\downarrow} \\
\psi_{L\uparrow}\\ \psi_{L\downarrow}
\end{pmatrix}$$